# How to create and save that file to Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a file and save it to Django model within a view without creating any temporary files or anything like that. I plan to write a .txt file that contains information and I want to save the .txt file in the Django model.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes – [ContentFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/files/file#django.core.files.base.ContentFile).

Assuming a model

```
class Blah(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(...)
```

you can use

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def view(request):
    content = b"Bla bla bla."
    file = ContentFile(content, name="my_file.txt")
    Blah.objects.create(file=file)
```

to create a model with something assigned to its file field without having had a file on disk.